# Passign parameters form google sheet to google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google scripts and I am having trouble with passing parameters from my google spreadsheet to my google script.

I have created a function in my script:

```
function functionname(ref) {
  Logger.log(ref);
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(ref).getValue();
  //do stuff with the value read from the sheet
  return modified_value;
}
```

and I am calling it in my google spreadsheet like:

```
=functionname(A4)
```

(the function is called from an empty A5 cell, with cell A4 filled with text).

I have initially tried with a static reference in the function, like:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("H9").getValue()
```

In this situation, it worked perfectly, but I do not want to replicate the function for each cell I need to operate, given I need to deliver this to non-programmers and the list of cells will increase.

Initially, I read that passing the parameters from the cell will be sufficient to receive the value and I had tried also this solution. Still, no matter what I try, the value of ref is always "undefined".

Can anyone please help me understand what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Your `=functionname(A4)` passes the value in A4 to your function.  You don't need the line `var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(ref).getValue();`

Comment: You are running from Spreadsheet context, not from script editor?

Answer (score 0):

No need for the SpreadSheetApps methods for custom function to pull the value from the SpreadSheet because it already gets the cell value that you are referencing. Just remove the `var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(ref).getValue();`

```
function functionname(ref) {
  Logger.log(ref);
  //do stuff with the value read from the sheet
  return modified_value;
}
```

You can call this function directly on your spreadsheet. Don't forget to store the new value on a variable and return it, or return the computed value directly.